# How to display HeaderValue on vf Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:tab label="Opportunity" id="TabTWO" style="font-weight:bold;width:200px;">
                  <apex:pageblock title="Opportunities">
                      <apex:pageblocksection >
                          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunities}" var="Opportunity"> 
                              <apex:column headerValue="RecordTypeId" value="{!Opportunity.RecordTypeId}" />
                              <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!Opportunity.name}"/>
                              <apex:column headerValue="StageName" value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>
                              <apex:column headerValue="CloseDate" value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                              <apex:column headerValue="Sales Representative" value="{!Opportunity.Sales_Rep__c}"/>
                              <apex:column headerValue="Date Of Appointment" value="{!Opportunity.Date_of_Appointment__c}"/>
                          </apex:pageBlockTable>
                      </apex:pageblocksection>
                  </apex:pageblock>            
              </apex:tab>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add <apex:sectionHeader title="One of Your Opportunities" subtitle="Exciting !"/>

Comment: Please share screen shot

Comment: @MohithKumar Im putting the scree Shot in Answer, I cant find any link to put Screen shot in comment

Answer (score 5):

**Updating following Screenshot**

So they say a picture speaks a thousand words! :) This now looks like a CSS issue to me, rather than anything wrong with the markup you posted in your question, as my demo shows. What other custom CSS do you have on the page?

It looks like the headers are being rendered just being clipped. If you use the Chrome's Developer Tools you will probably find the HTML is being output. It's the CSS that is hiding it. Try removing some of the custom CSS on your page bit by bit. Things like 'style' and 'class' attributes, as well as inline style tags and imports. Also worth trying other browsers, it's unlikely the Salesforce standard CSS is broken though, so my money is still on some custom CSS your using on the page.

**Working Sample**

Assuming your bindings are returning data (have you debugged this?). Then the VF markup in your example seems to work fine for me? I had to adjust your sample a little as I didn't have the full page or code to test this.

If this does not give you any clues, please include more detail on what your getting and confirm you've check the variables in your controller have the correct data, e.g. you have some rows.

The following code...

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="Opportunities">
    <apex:tabPanel>
        <apex:tab label="Opportunity" id="TabTWO"
            style="font-weight:bold;width:200px;">
            <apex:pageblock title="Opportunities">
                <apex:pageblocksection>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunities}" var="Opportunity">
                        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!Opportunity.name}" />
                        <apex:column headerValue="StageName"
                            value="{!Opportunity.StageName}" />
                        <apex:column headerValue="CloseDate"
                            value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Resulted in this...

[image]

Comment: Do i need to change controller to standard controller

Comment: I suspect thats not the answer, I was assuming the data your binding your table to is valid. My using the standard controller was just an easy way to get at some data on the basis your question was relating to some UI or VF markup issue. If you would like to elaborate on more on what your not or hoping to see, maybe with a screenshot, I can perhaps help you further.

Comment: im not getting the headervalue names on the column

Comment: Please can you give us more information to better help you. What do you mean 'im not getting the headervalue names'. Do you mean they are not being displayed? Maybe a screenshot or more sample code etc?

Comment: I mean HeaderValues are not being displayed, Know you can find the screen shot

Comment: Thanks, thats helped a lot, I've updated my answer, hopefully will help you trace the issue, which I don't believe is in the VF markup you included in your question btw, so thats fine. Take a look my updated answer, see what I'm suggesting in that helps...

Comment: No result even tried in different browsers

Comment: Any custom CSS? Maybe post a https://gist.github.com/ dump of the full page?